# Search within a database table based on an input where get it the textbox

Tags: asp.net

i write this code but this code nottrue.i want show rows table where pname=textbox1.text

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "select pid, pname, pprice,publisher, writer FROM tblproduct  where pname   LIKE '" + txtName.Text + "%';";

    GridView1.EmptyDataText = "search not result";        
}
```

Comment: Have you put a break point on the `SelectCommand` line to see what the actual text value of `txtName.Text` really is? Furthermore, have you taken the entire string assigned to `SelectCommand` and run that against the database in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: no, what is the `Text` property's value? and have you run the entire SQL statement and gotten any results back with it in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: my gridview show tblproduct when start page, when i click botton just show "search not result"

Comment: select pid, pname, pprice,publisher, writer FROM tblproduct  where pname =@pname

Comment: That SQL does not seem possible, where did the `LIKE` portion go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, because of the way the `SelectCommand` is built, instead use this:

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = @"select pid, pname, pprice, publisher, writer FROM tblproduct where pname LIKE @likeText;";

SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("likeText", txtName.Text);
```

As for why you are getting no results back, you need to debug the actual SQL syntax being generated and run that against your database manually, once that works, then you need to get that exact string to be generated in your `SelectCommand` assignment line of code above.